# Return a non-mapped Entity property based on a SUM of child records in the EntityFramework

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5

Using an example, I have the following two Entities.  The OrderEntity contains a collection of OrderLineEntites

```
public class OrderEntity 
{
  public string Reference { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public bool Confirmed { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public int OrderLineCount { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("Order")]
  public virtual ICollection<OrderLineEntity> OrderLineEntity__OrderEntity { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineEntity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }    
}
```

Using the following code I can load all the OrderLineEntities for all confirmed orders.

```
DbSet<OrderEntity> orderEntity.Where(x => x.Confirmed).Include(x => x.OrderLineEntity__OrderEntity)
```

What I need to do is set the non-mapped OrderLineCount property with the Count of the OrderLine records (to save actually loading them).

So for each loaded Order I have a fully populated Entity including the [NotMapped] property with an empty OrderLine collection.

Advise would be appreciated :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you have to change your approach.  You have to manually map the objects yourself:

```
var query = from a in context.Orders.Where(x => x.Confirmed)
select new OrderEntity
{
   Reference = a.Reference,
   Description = a.Description,
   Confirmed = a.Confirmed,
   OrderLineCount = a.OrderLineEntity__OrderEntity.Count
};
return query.ToList();
```